# Construction of reducible polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

We are given a polynomial $F(x)$. We are given enough coprime monic
polynomials $p_{i}(x)$ that we are free to choose.

Let $F_{i}(x) \equiv F(x) \pmod {p_{i}(x)} \neq 0$.

Considering $F_i(x)$ as a polynomial in $\Bbb Z[x]$, say we are free to choose polynomials $g_{i}(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$ of
degree($g_{i}(x)$) < degree($p_{i}(x))$ such
that:

$$F_{i}(x) + g_{i}(x) = s_{i}(x)t_{i}(x)$$

That is $F_{i}(x)$ when added with $g_{i}(x)$ factors into
$s_{i}(x)t_{i}(x)$ with the added condition that all non-zero coefficients of
$s_{i}(x)$,$t_{i}(x)$ are positive.

The question is if we use Chinese remainder theorem to find a
polynomial $G(x)$ from $g_{i}(x)$ (given sufficiently many),
then is it true that:

$$F(x) + G(x) = S(x)T(x)?$$

That is $F(x) + G(x)$ itself factors in $\Bbb Z[x]$ (Clearly the converse holds).

If this is always not possible under what extra conditions such a
factorization may hold in $\Bbb Z[x]$?

Comment: $x+2$ and $x$ are relatively prime in $\mathbb Z[x]$ but $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod {x+2}$ and $f(x)\equiv 1\pmod {x}$ cannot be solved in $\mathbb Z[x]$. You can do Chinese Remainder Theorem in $\mathbb Q[x]$, but you have to have some condition on the $p_i$ to be assured that the result is in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $x+2$ and $x$ are not relatively prime! Relatively prime means that $1$ is a linear combination.

Comment: @walcher Yes, if you use the ideal definition of coprime, that is true, but then you have the problem that $F_i$ aren't necessarily in $\mathbb Z[x]$, if the $p_i$ are not monic. So you really need more conditions on the $p_i$.

Comment: $p_{i}$ are monic and $F_{i}(x) \neq 0 \pmod {p_{i}(x)}$.

Comment: The title of this question is very undescriptive.

Comment: I was trying to say can we build reducibles from irreducibles? I believe the answer is not an easy yes as described here and something more is needed.